# HP TouchSmart 600 Touchscreen driver

Tags: touchscreen

I have a HP TouchSmart 600 and I installed Linux on the machine. Everything runs fine except the touchscreen.
I tryed it with the newest Ubuntu 32/64bit and also with Linux Mint 32/64bit.

Found this tutorial:
https://www.ebower.com/docs/ubuntu-touchsmart/#touchscreen

I installed the nwfermi driver, but the touchscreen still doesnt work. Have to use Linux because its a project from the university and I am not pro with Linux. So sorry for that stupid question ;)

Maybe someone has an idea or another tutorial. Would be very nice! Thank you guys

I got xinput-calibrator running, but the touchevent still doesnt work :(

Comment: There are also a couple of good trouble shooting steps here as well: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touchscreen

Answer (score 1):

```
   sudo apt-get install build-essential autoconf2.13 xorg-dev xserver-xorg-dev xutils-dev libtool debhelper
   sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 libc6-i386 lib32tinfo5 libc6-i386
   sudo dpkg -i xf86-input-nextwindow_0.3.4~precise1_amd64.deb
   sudo dpkg -i nwfermi-0.6.5.0_amd64.deb
```

thats what i used to get mine (touchsmart 600-1050) working everytime you install a diffrent kernel you have to reinstall the last two..hope it helps

Comment: Too bad the answer doesn't explain why  `xf86-input-nextwindow_0.3.4~precise1_amd64.deb` and `nwfermi-0.6.5.0_amd64.deb` have been installed manually and/or where they are available for download.

Comment: @Wonderer Can you update your answer for Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: @Ron, Regretfully I no longer have this system, but i do remember i was able to get it working on bionic beaver but it was so long ago i can't remember how sorry

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on the touchscreen on my antique HP TouchSmart 520 ever working again since installing Xubuntu, but this update of the nwfermi project restored that functionality: https://github.com/glorang/nwfermi