# How to get the touchscreen on HP TouchSmart 520 PC to work with Ubuntu?

Tags: hp, touchscreen

I've seen the question asked by David Swift on how to get the touchscreen working on the HP TouchSmart 520, but he never received an answer.  I'm hoping that by re-asking, I can (hopefully) get an answer or some help.

I installed Ubuntu on my HP TouchSmart 520 PC because Windows 7 security updates stopped January, and I didn't want to buy Windows 10 for such an old PC.  So I installed Ubuntu because I've used it before and I liked it.  Unfortunately the touchscreen functionality of the PC is no longer working, and I have no idea how to get it working again.

If someone could please help me out, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: I found this answer from an earlier version of Ubuntu and am wondering if it can be modernized to the current Ubuntu 20.04.  https://askubuntu.com/a/797456/453336 If I get success I will post the steps as an answer.